# Asterisk-Dahdi, get status channel

Tags: hardware, asterisk, voip

I have Asterisk 1.6 with a analogic card X100p that work properly. I want to detect if the card is in use or not (the status of the card).

Please any one get the problem before ?

Comment: this the output of the command "core show channels": > Channel Location State Application(Data) > 0 active channels 0 active calls 26 calls processed you think this is normal?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "show channels" command

```
voip*CLI> show channels
Channel              Location             State   Application(Data)             
DAHDI/3-1            s@ivr-3:12           Up      BackGround(someexample)
1 active channel
1 active call
```

You can differentiate a DAHDI device by the channel name.

Comment: this the output of the command "core show channels":

Channel              Location             State   Application(Data)             
0 active channels
0 active calls
26 calls processed

you think this is normal?

Comment: You mean about 0 Active Channels, 0 active calls? It means nobody is calling right now, if you can be sure there is a call running, then it's not normal.

Comment: it's work, i made a call and send the cmd "core show channels" and it's work.

Comment: Good, shouldn't you mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

`asterisk -rx "dahdi show channel 1" |grep Onhook >/dev/null || echo "In Use"`

Answer (score -1):

```
dahdi show channels
```

in the asterisk console to show what channels managed by dahdi are in use.
Also there's **dahdi show status**, but I'm not sure of the output.

Comment: "dahdi show status" show the status of the card, "dahdi show channel _ " dont give any information about the channel; if it's in use, busy,...

Comment: Are you sure you have configured your card to provide channels FXO's to asterisk? (usually it's /etc/asterisk/chan_dahdi.conf)

Comment: Yes it's work perfectly, i can make call through PTSN.

Comment: http://www.freepbx.org/forum/freepbx/users/x100p-channel-not-working -  seems there are some complains concerning this card model, hence the recommended method does not provide the needed output.